# Volatile integer and computer security

Tags: c, security, sh, volatile

Here's a problem I found in a book about Computer Security. It shows a code but doesn't explain why it's dangereous.

Can you explain it to me ?

Here's the problem :

```
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 

void f (char *s) 
{ 
    char buf[32]; 
    strcpy (buf, s); 
} 

int main (int argc, char **argv) 
{ 
    volatile int i = 0; 
    if (argc> 1) 
        f (argv[1]); 

    if (i) 
        system ("/bin/sh"); 

    return EXIT_SUCCESS; 
}
```

Thank you for answering !

Comment: Additionally to the to answers below: The volatile is not the problematic part, it´s only there to prevent the compiler from removing the variable because of optimization (because, other than buffer overflows, it´s clear what happens with it and it will be the same every time you start the program)

Answer (score 3):

The function `strcpy` does not check for the bounds of the buffer it writes into and hence can overflow if the string to be copied is too big for the buffer causing undefined behaviour and even program crash. You should use the safer alternative `strncpy`. It puts a limit on the number of bytes to be copied.

```
void f(char *s) { 
    char buf[32]; // can be a variable length array
    strncpy(buf, s, (sizeof buf) - 1); // copy at most 31 bytes
    buf[31] = '\0';  // make buf a string just in case strlen(s) > 31
}
```

If there is no null byte in the first 32 bytes in the buffer pointed to by `s`, then `buf` will not be null-terminated and all 32 bytes will be copied by `strncpy`. Therefore, if you want buf to be a string, then you should leave one place for the null byte and put it there at the end of `buf` yourself.

Comment: +1 for a good answer including the problem with a naked `strncpy()`.

Answer (score 1):

The function `f` copies the content of the first argument passed to the program into a buffer, but uses `strcpy` which does not perform any bounds checking. You could thus perform a buffer overflow attack and override the value of the `i` variable, which will then cause the program to yield a shell prompt.

Try this yourself - just call the program with an argument longer than 32 characters.

For comparison of `strcpy` and `strncpy` which is the safer alternative, see [their manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strncpy)

Answer (score 1):

This code is dangerous because of this line:

```
strcpy (buf, s);
```

The line is attempting to copy the passed string into a buffer of length 32. However, we set no length on how long to copy or how long the input string `s` could be. This is what's called a **Buffer Overflow**.  Due to this, arbitrary data (like strings that execute "evil" commands) could be placed into memory.

For example, if I used a string consisting of 32 spaces then the string "/bin/sh -c rm -rf /", as `s`, then the function might accidentally erase your hard drive! (well, technically, you'd need to be an administrator for that to work, but the example is effective)

To fix it, use `strncpy` instead, which takes an additional argument, the length to copy. This would make our dangerous line of code safe with:

```
strncpy(buf, s, 32);
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation ! But what you tell me doesn't work when I give a try, I juste have a Segmentation Fault or Illegal Instruction

Comment: @user3341638 If after replacing `strcpy (buf, s);` with `strncpy(buf, s, 32);`, code causes a segmentation fault, then there is something _else_ you changed or did not show in you post.

Comment: No, I got his when I try a 32 spaces string then "/bin/sh..."